# How do I create a list of similar controls in wix?

Tags: wix

Based on a list of values like `[A, Another, AThird]`, I want to display a list of similar control elements like

```
<control id="1">  
<text SourceFile="AFile.rtf"/>  
<Condition Action="hide"><![CDATA[SelectedMessage <> "A"]]></Condition>  
</control>
<control id="2">
<text SourceFile="AnotherFile.rtf"/>
<Condition Action="hide"><![CDATA[SelectedMessage <> "Another"]]></Condition>
</control>
<control id="3">
<text SourceFile="AThirdFile.rtf"/>
<Condition Action="hide"><![CDATA[SelectedMessage <> "AThird"]]></Condition>
</control>
```

Is there a way to do this? Can I generate it with heat.exe?  Is there a control form that allows me to render repeated content?

Answer (score 0):

Is the wix Feature tree UI what you are looking for? Are you trying to display these files to the user to install?